# Estimate the order of growth of algorithm from run time and ratio of change

Tags: algorithm, time-complexity

I'm a beginner practising with algorithms. Below list represents an algorithm I ran and recorded the times and ratio of change. I'm not sure how to figure out the order of growth from this list. What factors do I have to consider? I would very much appreciate an explanatory answer.

```
 N  |seconds | ratio | log(base of 2) ratio
---------------------------------------
512   0.12    4.14      2.05
1024  0.49    4.24      2.08
2048  2.08    4.24      2.08
4096  8.83    4.24      2.08
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Compare the times for your smallest input to the various larger inputs:

- A 2x increase in N (512->1024) results in a 4x increase in running time.
- A 4x increase in N (512->2048) results in a 16x increase in running time.
- An 8x increase in N (512->4096) results in a 64x increase in running time.

From this, you can extrapolate that a *k*x increase in N will result in an *k*<sup>2</sup>x increase in running time, indicating an O(*n*<sup>2</sup>) algorithm.

Comment: Exactly the answer I needed. Thank you :)